# Issue in GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have commited the code in GitHub but I am facing a problem to open the sample-ui folder. Can anyone help me? The picture of the problem we are facing is posted below:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don't see any error message or anything on that screenshot. What problem is it showing us?

Answer (score 1):

That means the folder is a nested git repository (you have a `.git/` subfolder in it).

If you don't need its history, you should:

```sh
git rm --cached sample-ui
rm -Rf sample-ui/.git
git add sample-ui
git commit -m "Add sample-ui content"
git push
```